# gitlab pre-receive hook python import error

Tags: gitlab, githooks, gitlab-omnibus

the following is my githook:

```
import os
print 'hi from draj pre-receive githook'
import gitlab, subprocess
```

When I ssh into my gitlab ubuntu instance and run it, it correctly prints 'hi from draj pre-receive githook' and exits with success.

However when I push to the repository the githook is installed for, i get:

```
remote:     import os, gitlab, subprocess
remote: ImportError: No module named gitlab
To https://gitlab.learningdollars.com/root/00-boilerplate-draj.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

I looked at these two posts: [How can I run a virtualenv python script as a git pre-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037284/how-can-i-run-a-virtualenv-python-script-as-a-git-pre-commit-hook) and [remote: ImportError: No module named gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544625/remote-importerror-no-module-named-gitlab) and they seem to suggest that the environment variables are the cause of the problem.

So I modified my githook to print the environment:

```
import os
print 'hi from draj pre-receive githook'
print 'os.environ: ', os.environ
import gitlab, subprocess
```

So I ran my pre-receive hook directly on my gitlab instance and I got:

```
hi from draj pre-receive githook
os.environ:  {'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'USERNAME': 'root', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'MAIL': '/var/mail/root', 'SUDO_UID': '[OBFUSCATED]', 'SUDO_GID': '[OBFUSCATED]', 'SUDO_COMMAND': '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/root/00-boilerplate-draj.git/custom_hooks/pre-receive', 'LOGNAME': 'root', 'USER': 'root', 'HOME': '/home/ubuntu', 'PATH': '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin', 'SUDO_USER': 'ubuntu', 'LS_COLORS': '[OBFUSCATED]'}
```

But, when I try to do a push that invokes the pre-receive hook I get:

```
(venv)Govindas-MacBook-Pro:boilerplate_draj govindadasu$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 284 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: hi from draj pre-receive githook
remote: os.environ:  {'HOME': '', 'GIT_DIR': '.', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '', 'GL_ID': 'user-1', 'PATH': '/opt/gitlab/bin:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:/opt/gitlab/embedded/libexec/git-core:/opt/gitlab/embedded/libexec/git-core:/opt/gitlab/bin:/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:/bin:/usr/bin'}
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/root/00-boilerplate-draj.git/custom_hooks/pre-receive", line 9, in <module>
remote:     import gitlab, subprocess
remote: ImportError: No module named gitlab
To https://gitlab.learningdollars.com/root/00-boilerplate-draj.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.learningdollars.com/root/00-boilerplate-draj.git'
```

But what those articles don't provide is how exactly am I supposed to modify the environment using the pre-receive githook in order to be able to import gitlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[remote: ImportError: No module named gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544625/remote-importerror-no-module-named-gitlab) had a hint towards the solution but it didn't work for me since bash pre-receive hooks didn't work on my gitlab instance only python ones did. So I created a generic pre-receive:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, subprocess
subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/python2.7', './custom_hooks/pre-receive.py'])
```

and as you can see just invoked the actual pre-receive from it using an installation of python which was working in an environment that had gitlab installed.